# Chrome extension update extension'sview after execute background script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I would like to show a div with the response of the server in the extension's tab.
My problem is that the div is not defined in my background.js.

I use this code to execute some functions :

```
  saveButton.addEventListener('click', async () => {
    let [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true });

    chrome.scripting.executeScript({
      target: { tabId: tab.id },
      function: saveProperty,
     });
  });
```

My problem is that my div is not defined in the "saveProperty" function.

**EDIT**

The div is defined in the extension's tab.

```
let showError = document.getElementById('showError');
```

The saveProperty function is used to get the content of a webpage and save in a database software.

This extension is used to make **webscraping**.

```
function saveProperty() {
  chrome.storage.sync.get(
    ['api_key', 'current_table'],

    [...]

    function sendData() {
      let req = new XMLHttpRequest();
      req.open("POST", url, true);
      req.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      req.addEventListener("load", function () {
        if (req.status >= 200 && req.status < 400) {

          // I get the error : showError is not defined.
          showError.textContent = 'Saved';
          showError.style = 'display:block';
          showError.style.backgroundColor = '#6dae24';
          setTimeout(function() {
            showError.style = 'display:none';
          }, 1500);

        } else {
          console.error(req.status + " " + req.statusText + " " + url);
          console.error(req.responseText);
        }
      });
      req.addEventListener("error", function () {
        console.error(req.responseText);
      });
      req.send(json);
    }
  });
}
```

Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: Thank you very much wOxxOm ! Don't hesitate to tell me if I forgot something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`executeScript` runs the code in a different page (the web page) which naturally doesn't have that div element.

The solution is to handle that div in its page. For example, your injected function can send a message:

```js
saveButton.addEventListener('click', async () => {
  const [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true});

  chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function onMessage(msg, sender) {
    if (sender.tab?.id === tab.id) {
      chrome.runtime.onMessage.removeListener(onMessage);
      Object.assign(document.getElementById('showError'), msg.props);
    }
  });

  chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: {tabId: tab.id},
    function: saveProperty,
  });
});

function saveProperty() {
  //............
  if (ok) {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
      props: {
        textContent: 'Saved',
        style: 'display:block; background-color: #6dae24',
      },
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Does async/await work now with chrome apis?

Comment: It's being implemented, see https://crbug.com/328932 and use [this](https://chromiumdash.appspot.com/commits) to find which version of Chrome has the commit that implements a particular API. For example chrome.scripting is in Chrome 91 whereas chrome.tabs is in 88.